# Can't click on ListView whose rows are made of WebViews

Tags: android, list, listview, webview, android-arrayadapter

I have an Activity which extends **ListView**
The ListView that I use is an extension of **ArrayAdapter** and each row of the ListView primarily consists of a **WebView**

The problem is that touching the WebView does not call **OnListItemClick**.

***Any thoughts on how I can be able to touch the webview and call OnListItemClick?
Or is there something else that I'm doing wrong?***
Thanks!

Here is a skeleton of the Activity class, along with the relevant XML files for the layout

PS, I've tried setting android:clickable="false" in my layout, but this doesn't let me click on the rows of my ListView.
Interestingly, I can *still* scroll through the list, but I just can't click!

```
public class ListOfItemsFromTopicActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Topic t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_from_topic_skeleton);

        TopicFactory tf                 = new TopicFactory();
        t                               = tf.build_topic(3);
        ListView itemlist               = getListView();
        ListOfItemsAdapter adapter      = new ListOfItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.items_from_topic_row, t.getItems());
        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // do some stuff that never gets done
    }

    private class ListOfItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        private int                     text_view_resource_id;
        private LayoutInflater          layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        public ListOfItemsAdapter(Context context, int a_text_view_resource_id, ArrayList<Item> some_items) {
            super(context, a_text_view_resource_id, some_items);
            this.items                  = some_items;
            this.text_view_resource_id  = a_text_view_resource_id;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v              = layout_inflater.inflate(this.text_view_resource_id, null);
            Item o              = items.get(position);
            WebView page        = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.item);
            page.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://a/bcde", o.getShort_title(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

items_from_topic_skeleton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/blackgrad"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/section_title"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
    <ListView
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

items_from_topic_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:padding="5dip"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="55dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dip"
                >
            <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/item"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/disclosure"
                android:layout_height="29dip"
                android:layout_width="29dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:src="@drawable/disclosure"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you found the solution? if yes than please share your solution !

Answer (score 2):

If you add a focusable element to a ListView, it causes the ListView items to no longer be selectable. Try setting `android:clickable = false` on your WebView.

Comment: doesn't work. i also tried to add a "focusable element" <input type="text" />, but this had no effect either

Comment: Worked for me, had a listview with an onClick and a Button inside with a separate. Changed the inner button to a ImageView with onClick and now both clicks work, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Just make your onTouch event to do whatever you want.

e.g: My list item consists of TextView, WebView and Linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webvie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to perform on click action - on the whole listitem.

```
 holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
```

But when I run my app, only texview is clickable. What to do? Set up onTouch listener on webView:

```
holder.webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                holder.layout.callOnClick();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

supports only API 15+ tough...