# How to set keyboard focus on WebView?

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a simple WebView example app that has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is /res/layout/main.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/urlToLoad"
    android:hint="Type url to load"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <Button android:id="@+id/webviewgo"
    android:text="Go"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false" />

  <com.example.exWebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />    

</LinearLayout>
```

It works as expected, but I am interested in **routing a keyboard event to the WebView**. Currently, even if I select the WebView (and scroll etc.), when I type any key, it goes to the EditText control... which is not what I want.

How do I make a keyboard event go to the WebView instead?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293965/android-webview-focus-problem), all you have to do is set, inside the main activity's OnCreate(), an OnTouchListener() with a requestFocus():

```
    mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) { 
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                           if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                               v.requestFocus(); 
                           } 
                           break; 
                   } 
                   return false; 
                }
        });
```

What this code basically does is lock focus on any down or up event the moment it reaches your view. Note how it returns false, so that the event can further propagate to other views, as if it weren't handled.

Comment: In my case I had to use requestFocusFromTouch() instead of just requestFocus().