# Android: Back button bypasses onKeyDown and closes application

Tags: android, button, webview, back, onkeydown

I have a program with 4 different tabs.

One of these tabs is an ActivityGroup which has a ListView in it. When I click on one of the list items, it switches to WebActivity:

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(TabActivity2.this, WebActivity.class);
              Bundle b = new Bundle();
              b.putString("URL", URLs[(int)id]);
              b.putString("prevActivity", "TabActivity2");
              intent.putExtras(b);
              replaceContentView("web", intent);
          }
        });
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); this.setContentView(view);
    }
```

So now we're in the WebActivity class. Here's the code:

```
public class WebActivity extends ActivityGroup {
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String URL = b.getString("URL");

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FirstTabWebViewClient());        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String retActivity = b.getString("prevActivity");
        if (retActivity == "TabActivity2") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(WebActivity.this, TabActivity2.class);
            replaceContentView("list_webpages", intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); this.setContentView(view);
    }
```

Here's the strange thing: If I click on the back button right after I enter the WebActivity class, it closes the application.

But if I first click on any link inside the WebView and then press back twice, then it returns me to the original activity with the ListView.

From using break points in Eclipse I discovered that the program does not even visit onKeyDown if I press the Back button right after I enter the WebActivity view. However, if I click on any link within the WebView and then press the back button, then it goes through my onKeyDown method.

What is going on here??

Comment: And the task loading webpage is better to be in AsyncTask or Intent Service to trigger as the nwtwork condition is unstable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WebView doesn't have the focus, which causes the back button to be triggered on top of that (the application stack). If you click on a link it get's back focus. The WebView has some strange issues concerning focus, have look at this post: [Android WebView focus problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293965/android-webview-focus-problem)

There you will also find some suggested workarounds to get the focus, you need to call requestFocus() on the WebView at the right place.

Comment: Yes! It indeed turned out to be a focus problem. Thank you.