# Android WebView and AdMob causing app to crash when used together

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am currently having an issue. I have **AdMob** ads on my android app with `WebView`. They are all in the same group. I have my top banner displaying great, and my bottom banner displaying amazingly great with the `WebView`. The problem is, when the ads are refreshing, I cannot click a link on the `WebView` without the app crashing. Is there any way around this issue?

I have been searching for hours and have found nothing other than knowing that AdMob adds also work with `WebView`. So I would think somehow having 2 adds and 1 `WebView` (maybe something to do with having 3 `WebView` in the same group is an issue?). So its time I ask the community.

Thanks everyone and will definitely note all responses.

Comment: Since AdViews are themselves WebViews perhaps focus is lost - try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927549/how-to-focus-on-webview-upon-selecting-an-edittext-within-same-layout-in-android

Comment: Na that isn't it. Its something to do with the webview I am using and the ads loading at the same time. Because I can let the ad finish loading and resume using my webview just fine. I just have to wait for ad to finish loading and I know its done loading because the close (X) symbol will dissappear.

Comment: Post a logcat with the crash along with which device/OS you are using.

Comment: No logcat and sprectrum 2 LG which has android version 4.1.2 on it. Im telling you, Lol. The only time my app crashes (by crash I mean it just forces it to minimize, then when maximizing again, it starts over) is when my Ads are in the process of loading. If they are not in the process of loading, I can use my webview just fine.

Comment: All I can suggest is to put your app under MAT and figure out how much memory pressure those ads are putting your on app. Does it happen when you only have one AdView slot rather than two?

Comment: Yea, it even happens with one ad. At first I thought it could have been some kind of memory issue. But now I feel that maybe the webviews all share an onLoad event or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is against Admob policy to have more than one AdView on an Activity.

It is quite possible that having 2 AdViews is causing you the problem.
Remove one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea and that probably would explain the weird behavior. Will remove one now.