# input tag focus do not open my visual keyboard when open new webview

Tags: javascript, html, webview

My case is, open new `webview` and load my html `search` page.

I use `input.focus()` try to open my visual keyboard. But it seems not working.

So, why it does not working? And How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code looks like but you can try put autofocus in your html input tag and give that a run.

```
<input autofocus>
```

also what does your javascript look like and what are you using to look at the site?

Comment: I know html way `autofocus` property and js way `document.getElementById('input').focus()`, But if the case _point_ is __open new webview and load html page__, not just navigate to other page through `<a>` tag or SPA route change.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with webview but I've seen that `webView.requestFocus();` may work.

Also this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293965/android-webview-focus-problem

Comment: I am not familiar too. I am looking for a Web Front-End way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use several Pseudo Class like:

:hover, :active, :focus, :visit